# How to dynamically change css styles on a single element using class names in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this might have been asked before, but I just cannot find the answer I am looking for. I have a single element (h1) and I have a bunch of radio buttons styled as regular buttons. I want to change styles on the h1 element by adding a class, depending on which radio button is clicked ("checked"). The problem I am having is every time I select a different button, the class is added to the element which is what I want but the previous classes remain. The only way I fixed this is by using a brute force approach, which is not ideal if I have more than a few styles.

attempt on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebzjknqo/4/

**HTML CODE**

```js
const button = document.forms.namedItem('color');

const changeColor = (color) => {
  const title = document.querySelector('#title');

  // for (let cssClass of title.classList) {
  // if (title.classList.length === 0) {
  title.classList.add(`title-${color}`);
  console.log('classlist: ', title.classList);
  // }
  // title.classList.replace(cssClass, `title-${color}`);
  // console.log('CSSCLASS: ', cssClass);
  // }

  title.innerHTML = `i am ${color}`;
};

button.addEventListener('change', (e) => changeColor(e.target.value));
```

```css
#title {
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

/* RADIO BUTTONS */
#button-group {
  text-align: center;
}

#button-group label {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border: rgb(117, 114, 114) solid 1px;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0.7em 1.5em;
}

#button-group input[type='radio'] {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0;
  display: none;
}

#button-group label:hover {
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.title-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.title-red {
  color: red;
}

.title-orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <h1 id="title">Hello World</h1>
  <div id="button-group">
    <form name="color">
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="btn-red"
        name="btn"
        value="red"
        onchange="changeColor(this.value)"
      />
      <label for="btn-red">Red</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="blue"
        name="btn"
        value="blue"
        onchange="changeColor(this.value)"
      />
      <label for="blue">Blue</label>
     <input
        type="radio"
        id="orange"
        name="btn"
        value="orange"
        onchange="changeColor(this.value)"
      />
      <label for="orange">Orange</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property className for clearing the class attribute.

```js
const button = document.forms.namedItem('color');

const changeColor = (color) => {
  const title = document.querySelector('#title');
  title.className = '';
  title.classList.add(`title-${color}`);
  title.innerHTML = `i am ${color}`;
};

button.addEventListener('change', (e) => changeColor(e.target.value));
```

```css
#title {
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

/* RADIO BUTTONS */
#button-group {
  text-align: center;
}

#button-group label {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border: rgb(117, 114, 114) solid 1px;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0.7em 1.5em;
}

#button-group input[type='radio'] {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0;
  display: none;
}

#button-group label:hover {
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.title-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.title-red {
  color: red;
}

.title-orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <h1 id="title">Hello World</h1>
  <div id="button-group">
    <form name="color">
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="btn-red"
        name="btn"
        value="red"
        onchange="changeColor(this.value)"
      />
      <label for="btn-red">Red</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="blue"
        name="btn"
        value="blue"
        onchange="changeColor(this.value)"
      />
      <label for="blue">Blue</label>
     <input
        type="radio"
        id="orange"
        name="btn"
        value="orange"
        onchange="changeColor(this.value)"
      />
      <label for="orange">Orange</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in html5 there is functions for removing and adding css class Attributes

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('MyClass');

document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('MyClass');

if ( document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.contains('MyClass') ) 

document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.toggle('MyClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator & change it based on your condition preference

```
a ? true:false;

classname={"existingclassnames "+condition ? "classname1":"classname2"};
```

Note: Always give spacebar after existingclassnames

Rightway:existingclassnames classname1(or)2 based on your condition

Wrongway:existingclassnamesclassname1(or)2 based on your condition